# Activerecord migrations, making t.references correctly point to a custom ID type, string not integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

Below I have a migration for the "test" model which uses it's own primary key, a String instead of an Integer.

```
    class CreateTest < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :test, id: false do |t|

          t.string  :id,          primary_key: true

          t.timestamps
        end        
      end
    end
```

Now we have the "client" model that `t.references` test.

```
    class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :clients do |t|

          t.references :test,   null: false

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```

The issue is that `t.references` assumes it's an integer id.

```
    # == Schema Information
    #
    # Table name: clients
    #
    #  id         :integer          not null, primary key
    #  test_id    :integer          not null
    #  created_at :datetime         not null
    #  updated_at :datetime         not null
```

This is obviously wrong as `Test.id` is a string.

Is there some magic I need to do to have the `t.references` "know" that it's a string based on the model or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you using the string value as the primary key?

Comment: Playing mostly =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to the migration with the `references`:

```
type: :string
```

> The reference column type. Defaults to :integer.

[You can read more here.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference)

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work but I just tried it again and it did.. so *hangs head* thanks +1

Answer (score 4):

Just add a `type` to your definition of the reference:

```
t.references :test, type: :string, null: false
```

Comment: I swear I tried that and it didn't work but I just tried it again and it did.. so *hangs head* thanks +1  and you answered the same time as Jolly so I'm going to give him the answer..

Answer (score 2):

Could you not use:

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|

      t.string :test_id,   null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is how I was solving it but I assumed there was a better way.. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome - I didn't actually know of the `:type` option for `references`, so would say one of the other answers is more appropriate for this.